# Facebook Graph API - Get all pages and APP manages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to query for all access_tokens or page_ids that an app has access to?  Instinctively I thought I could do me/accounts?access_token= but it looks like it returns all the pages I have access to, not necessarily the ones the app is authorized to manage.

So I know I can check for an access token by calling each page and passing my page access token aka: `<graph>/page_id?access_token=xxxx&fields=access_token`

I saw that most of these tokens are also in me/accounts but I really am trying to get the view of what pages an APP is managing.  That make sense?

1. Preferably I am looking for a way to get page_id's+access tokens but I would be willing to settle for a graph call that returns all page_ids that I manage, and I will manually query each one.
2. Do all accounts that I have access to via an app, also show up in my `me/accounts`?

Any suggesitions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my issue was me/accounts was skewed because I granted permission to the app to "manage pages."  As a result any app that am admin for will show up in the me/accounts?access_token=.

Your options for geting access tokens are:

1. `me/accounts?access_token=<app_token>`
2. `/page_id/?fields=access_token&access_token=<app_token>`

Answer (score 0):

is this a page tab and you want to query what pages it is installed to? Or are you saying your app has asked for the accounts permission and you want to know what it can post to? If the latter I think you should be able to post to all pages associated with the account. This should return the page_id and the access_token
 https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts

Comment: You're right it doesn't limit by app. But if your app has manage_pages then it can post to any of those with the access_token you retrieve. As I say, is this a page_tab application and you only want the pages it is installed to?

Comment: I posted notes above hopefully they are correct.  I am basically want to do some validation on when tokens expire as well as make sure our tokens for the apps are still valid.  These are both page tabs and apps...

Comment: Well you can only use a user_access token to query the accounts connection,and as manage_pages grants access to all pages,I think the only way you would know what app made the request is by the fact that they're using that app at the time,which means you should have access to the specific app_id.this query might be useful.But it only returns a bool for the app making the request https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3Dselect%20page_id%2Chas_added_app%20from%20page%20WHERE%20page_id%20IN(SELECT%20page_id%20FROM%20page_admin%20WHERE%20uid%3Dme())

Comment: it stripped some brackets from the end. you need to add "())" to then end of it - without the " obviously so the query should read "select page_id,has_added_app from page WHERE page_id IN(SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid=me())"

Comment: it makes a request as the app you're using, so you know whether the app currently being used has access. When you make a request to /me/accounts you must know what access_token the app is using as you have to be in a specific app to begin with. I'm not 100& sure what you're trying to accomplish and I'm beginning to confuse myself I'm afraid!